# What is the difference between ～んとする and ～うとする?

Tags: volitional-form

I ran into ～んとする the other day and I think I get the hang of how it works and what meaning it conveys, but it seems eerily similar to that of ～うとする.

I know Japanese have a lot of different ways to say the same thing, so I wonder if there's no other difference apart from conjugation between these two. In other words, I wonder if the following examples mean the same:

> 見る → 見らんとする
> 見る → 見ようとする

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- 見んと (<見むと) is more literary/archaic and can be more bookish than 見ようと.
  <sub>(You don't say 見らんと)</sub>
- 見んとする (<見むとする) <sup>*</sup>   consists of: み (未然形, imperfective form of 見る) + archaic volitional auxiliary ん (む) + particle と + verb する
  <sub>* You might also encounter an archaic verb す used instead of する , as in 見んとす.</sub>
- 見ようとする consists of: み + volitional auxiliary よう + particle と + verb する

A few examples:

> せんと, 送らんと, 書かんと, 言わんと... ← literary
>   しようと, 送ろうと, 書こうと, 言おうと... ← modern