# 「生かんとする」 in a relative clause

Tags: translation, volitional-form

These are part of the lyrics of the fifth ending theme of Hunter x Hunter (the 2011 animation).

> 朝{あさ}をむさぼり 夜{よる}を吐{は}き出{だ}し
>
> 生{い}かんとする 我{わ}が性{さが}

It seems 「生かんとする」 means 「生きようとする」:

```
生く(archaic form of 生きる) → 生か (未然形) + む(ん)とする
```

but I'm not sure whether it is a relative clause here.

Does the second line mean "my nature of trying to live", like, as part of my true nature, I try to live? Or maybe 「生かんとする」 isn't a relative clause at all? Since it's a song, I'm not sure.

I don't understand what "to try to exist/live" means exactly, either. Especially since `volitional + とする` is supposed to carry the nuance of being unsuccessful.

It seems 生く can also mean 生かす (to keep alive), so could 「我が性」 actually be the direct object of 「生かんとする」? Can I use `volitional + とする` as a relative clause modifying the direct object of the verb in volitional form if I'm the agent? Like:

> 使おうとしたパソコン
> the computer I tried to use (and failed)

Related question about んとする: [What is the difference between ～んとする and ～とする?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/what-is-the-difference-between-%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-and-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

Comment: +1, but wouldn't the correct form be 生きんとする?

Comment: @l'électeur I thought so too, that's why I'm guessing the verb that's being used there is actually the obsolete 生{い}く.

Comment: In the sense of 生かす, [生く follows the 下二段活用](https://www.google.com/amp/s/kobun.weblio.jp/content/amp/%25E7%2594%259F%2b%25E3%2581%258F), so its 未然形 would be 生け- and not 生か-.

Comment: You can understand what "to try to live" means in the sense of "survive / keep living / stay alive" right? A common theme when talking about human nature. I think that is the nuance of the line. (Translating volitional as "try" often clouds the real meaning.)